# Packed Bubble Chart - using angular - how can we add a click event on the outer bubble

Tags: angular, charts, highcharts

We are using angular in our front end and we want to add a click event for packed bubble split chart.
How can we do that?

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/packed-bubble-split

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The outer bubble represents the whole series, so you need to add click event on the specific series or on the `plotOptions.series` (for all series).

```
  plotOptions: {
    packedbubble: {
      events: {
        click() {
          console.log(this)
        }
      },
    }
}
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d3xLyb68/

**API References:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bubble.events.click
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bubble.events.click